# SaltStack: use `include:` twice in one sls file

Tags: salt-stack

I would like to use `include:` twice in a sls file:

```
include:
  - foo.bar

{% for system in salt['foo.get_systems'](pillar) %}
   ...
{% endfor %}

include:
  - this.is.the.end
```

But this fails with this message:

```
- Rendering SLS 'base:example.test' failed: while constructing a mapping
    in "<unicode string>", line 4, column 1
  found conflicting ID 'include'
    in "<unicode string>", line 106, column 1
```

I guess `conflicting ID 'include'` means that I can't use `include:` twice.

What can I do to execute something after the for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

State files are not guaranteed to be executed in a script-like order. They describe a data structure that dictates which state functions need to be run, but you should not think about them as though they are scripts, because they aren't.

You need to "include" all the SLS files that you will be including in a single include statement, and then if you need to make sure that certain states are run before or after other states, you should use the state [requisite](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html) parameters like `require`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have more than 20 states in one sls file. This means I need to use `require` 19 times? Every state needs to require the previous if I want to execute them one after the other?

Comment: That's exactly right. If they truly need to be run in sequence, and need to fail if the previous state fails, then yes, you should use the require parameters.  Think of it as being accurate in your description of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can walk around this by working with two sls files.

Move your current sls file ("example/test.sls" which contains the for-loop) to "example/step_one.sls". Then create a new file with this content:

```
include:
  - example.step_one
  - this.is.the.end
```